# Get HTML and CSS from grapes.js newsletter editor in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, grapesjs

**How to get output HTML and CSS of grapes.js in Javascript ?**

I am writing a Django app for newsletter, in which I need a newsletter editor for which I used **"grapes.js"** newsletter. Everything is fine but I am stuck in part where I need to get the HTML and CSS of the template created with it.
I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var editor = grapesjs.init({
  container : '#gjs',
  plugins: ['gjs-preset-newsletter'],
  pluginsOpts: {
    'gjs-preset-newsletter': {
      modalTitleImport: 'Import template',
    'grapesjs-plugin-export': { /* options */ }
      // ... other options
    }
  }
});
function returnHtml(){ 
    console.log('test')
    const mjml = editor.getHtml;
    preview = editor.getHtml
    $("#myiframe").contents().find("body").html(mjml)
}
returnHtml();
```

This code gives me the html of the template but without the css !

I have tried https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-mjml/issues/2. Can someone please suggest me what i am missing ? 
Thanks.

EDIT: I have an answer below but what i need is like this with html and css together like in export HTML.Thanks again. [image: https://screenshots.firefox.com/u752bu0nNN97rXlr/127.0.0.1]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Getting only HTML:

```
var html = editor.getHtml();
```

Getting only CSS:

```
var css = editor.getCss();
```

**Getting HTML with CSS inline**:

```
var htmlWithCss = editor.runCommand('gjs-get-inlined-html');
```

Comment: may I ask you to have a look  at a GrapesJS related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679919/grapesjs-and-php-store-and-load-data-to-show-in-editor-and-as-html-page-as-wel ?

Comment: Hi, is it still actual? I am trying to look the docs for `gjs-get-inlined-html` command and can't find any yet. I just wanted to know if this will include the javascripts of the page

Comment: gjs-get-inlined-html     function is only available for   "grapesjs-preset-newsletter" plugin:  https://github.com/artf/grapesjs-preset-newsletter

Answer (score 2):

It was simple. To get the CSS of the page,i did `editor.getCss()` It gave the page css, then joined HTML and CSS to get the complete Code.

finally i have something like this.

```
function returnHtml(){ 
    const mjml = editor.getHtml;
    css = editor.getCss()
    $("#myiframe").contents().find('head').append(`<style>${css}</style>`)
    $("#myiframe").contents().find("body").html(mjml)
}
```

From https://grapesjs.com/docs/api/editor.html#gethtml

Comment: may I ask you to have a look at a grapesJS related question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61679919/grapesjs-and-php-store-and-load-data-to-show-in-editor-and-as-html-page-as-wel ?

Answer (score 0):

This one will log your desired inline HTML.

```
function getInline() {
   console.log(editor.Commands.run('gjs-get-inlined-html'))
 }
```

Comment: It's work only with "grapesjs-preset-newsletter" plugin.